# When and how did Britons' (and offshoots like Americans) aversion to eating some parts of animals/fish (e.g. head/organs/blood/feet) begin?

Tags: food

Britons (and their offshoots the Americans and others) are today averse to eating some parts of animals/fish (e.g. head/organs/blood/feet). For example, [chicken feet](https://freakonomics.com/2011/12/the-economics-of-chicken-feet-and-other-parts/) were worthless in the US until c. 1991 when they began exporting them to China.

My guess (perhaps mistaken) is that any such wasteful practice is a luxury affordable only in modern times. Historically/evolutionarily, humans could not afford to simply discard perfectly edible parts of animals/fish they had caught.

So when and how did Britons/Americans/etc. begin their aversion to certain animal parts? Or was this "always" something that was practiced as far as is known to history or prehistory?

Comment: I don't know where this claim comes from. Britons eat blood in black pudding, the head in brawn, offal in dozens of dishes, and feet in sausages (although they might not know too much about that last one). The premise of your question is wrong.

Comment: Every culture has its own peculiarities. What's a delicacy to some is abhorrent to others. If you don't like to waste food, you should eat apple peels and bugs. They're both edible.

Comment: @DrMcCleod: I did not claim that zero Brits *ever* eat *any* blood/feet/head/offal. Instead, my claim was a more modest one of aversion. Brits do routinely discard much animal parts (worthless in the UK) but worth much more elsewhere. See [this 2013 article](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/foodanddrink/foodanddrinknews/10309562/Let-them-eat-chicken-feet-drive-to-sell-offal-and-animal-feet-abroad-as-delicacies.html) discussing the possibility of the UK exporting animal parts (that were otherwise going to landfill).

Comment: @Jos: I'm not sure if you were trying to provoke me, but believe it or not, I do always eat apple "peels". (They aren't "peels" for me since I don't peel them.) I have also eaten insects, but in most developed countries, they still aren't regularly farmed yet so it is not easy to buy them (though this will hopefully change in the coming decades).

Comment: I think this is pretty recent, probably post-war.  Traditional foods such as soups, sausages, haggis or faggots have always contained offal and were consumed by the poorer parts of society.  I've heard it said that the only parts of a pig not used were its squeal and the curl in its tail.

Comment: @user24096 I am not convinced that there is even a general aversion to doing so. There may be a preference for other cuts of meat, but that doesn't mean that there is an aversion to the ones that you mention.

Comment: I'm not provoking you. But thanks for confirming what I already suspected.

Comment: I think this is a pretty recent thing.  There was an area of a market where I grew up that sold tripe, lights, tongue, brains, pigs trotters etc.  It was a fairly gruesome place for a kid to wander around.  Steak and kidney pie, and liver and bacon are still popular.

Comment: Could you make that specific, please? Which group have you heard of that 's not averse to eating various parts of various critters?

Comment: @DrMcCleod - here in Bristol (UK) where I live, a shop has recently closed that , for over 100 years, sold 'Bath chaps' (small hams made from a pig's cheek with part of tongue rolled up inside) and cooked pigs' trotters. Bulls' 'pizzles' are still sold in some places, although these days I think mostly for dogs to eat.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Was/is eating such items perceived as low-class/cheap? Or somehow bad/improper?

Comment: @user24096 - they were inexpensive, but not considered bad or improper.